# regular expression matching in java

Tags: java, regex

Here is my example file :

```
lineone one
RUN lineone two
lineone three
RUN lineone four
```

I want to select all lines not starting with run, here is how I did it :

```
^([^RUN])
```

Is it possible to match all lines not starting with RUN and then append them to the back of the previous line ? like this

```
lineone one RUN lineone two
lineone three RUN lineone four
```

Comment: Your question doesn't describe what your example shows. In your example you are appending lines that *do* start with RUN to the end of the previous line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your example is correct you just need to replace `"\nRUN"` with `" RUN"`.

```
System.out.println(yourString.replaceAll("\nRUN", " RUN"));
```

Result:

```
lineone one RUN lineone two
lineone three RUN lineone four
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/8EehM)

Answer (score 3):

use [`str.startsWith("RUN");`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
^([^RUN])
```

does not work correctly as it will match any line that does not start with either R, U or N.

You should use lookahead:

```
^(?!RUN)
```

This should do what you want:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\n(RUN)", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("lineone one\nRUN lineone two\nlineone three\nRUN lineone four");
String replaceAll = matcher.replaceAll(" $1");
System.out.println(replaceAll);
```